# Removing all spaces in an ArrayList. Java

Tags: java, arraylist, trim

I am taking input from a .txt file and storing it into an ArrayList. I need to get rid of all the spaces so I can parse the `ArrayList` to an `<Integer>`. I am going to post commented out sections so you can see what i have tried to use to do this. Thank you. If you can give me somewhere to look that would be great.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class LabWriterReadre {

  public static void main(String [] args){
       BufferedReader br = null;
       BufferedWriter bw = null;
      // fileWriter = new FileWriter("output.txt",false);
       ArrayList<String> storage = new ArrayList<String>();
       ArrayList<String> convertToInt = new ArrayList<String>();
       ArrayList<Integer> matrix = new ArrayList<Integer>();
         String strLine = "";
        int row1,col1,row2,col2; 

        try {
            br = new BufferedReader( new FileReader("C:/Users/jeremiahlukus/Desktop/New folder/jj.txt"));
            while( (strLine = br.readLine()) != null)
            {
                System.out.println(strLine);
                storage.add(strLine);             
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.println("Unable to find the file: fileName");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Unable to read the file: fileName");
        }


        /*
        String[] trimmedArray = new String[string.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < string.size(); i++)
        {
            trimmedArray[i] = string[i].trim();
            string.removeAll(Arrays.asList(null,""));
        }
        */
        //string.removeAll(Collections.singleton(""));
       // string.removeAll(Arrays.asList(null,"")

      for (String str : storage)
      {
         if (//str != " ")
             !str.isEmpty())
         {
          convertToInt.add(str);
          //convertToInt.trim();

         }
     }

System.out.println(convertToInt);
}

 /* 

       row1 = Integer.parseInt(convertToInt.get(0));
       col1 = Integer.parseInt(convertToInt.get(1));
       row2 = Integer.parseInt(convertToInt.get(2));
       col2 = Integer.parseInt(convertToInt.get(3));

       int[][] matrix1=new int[row1][col1];
       int[][] matrix2=new int[row2][col2];

     */  

      //  System.out.println(row1);


        /*
```

This is the .txt file I am reading, `_` means space

```
3___________3
3_4

1 ______2 3 
4_5 _6
7 _8 _9

1 _2_ 3_ 4
5 _6 _7 _8
9_ 10_ 11_ 12
```

This is the ArrayList printed out

```
[3______3,_3 _4,__ 1_______2_ 3 , ___4 _5 _6, 7_ 8 _9, 1_ 2_ 3_ 4, 5 _6_ 7_ 8, 9 _10_ 11_ 12]
```

This is what I want to happen

```
[3,3,3,4,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
```

Comment: Sorry but what specific problem you are facing while writing your code? What is your question?

Comment: Sorry, I posted the output

Comment: I see some empty elements in your expected results like `6,,7` (there are two commas). Is that intentional or typo?

Comment: No,  i corrected it.

Comment: I think you've replaced spaces with underscores, but there are still spaces in your example; what do those mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may be wrong but it looks like your code could be solved and simplified a little with something like

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("C:/Users/jeremiahlukus/Desktop/New folder/jj.txt"));
List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
while(input.hasNextInt()){
    numbers.add(input.nextInt());
}
```

I am assuming here that your file contains only numbers separated by whitespaces (which includes also line separators).

Comment: lol great. I did not know you could do this. This is awesome.

Comment: Yes thank you I was making sure this solved it. Thank you this takes care of all the other problems I was having.

Answer (score 3):

Every single row could be parsed with a regular expression like this

```
List<String> sequence = new ArrayList<String>();
Patter noSpacesPattern = Pattern.compile("(\\S+)");
Matcher matches;

// reading your line from file here, now for each line do this

matches = noSpacesPattern.matcher(strLine);

while (matches.find())
    sequence.add(matches.group());
```

This will sanitize from unnecessary spaces and will keep your code pretty readable.

Answer (score 2):

You could just do replace(" ", "") when adding the line. Also, this code could be made much more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove all the spaces using `replaceAll()` when you are reading your file in the array.

```
while( (strLine = br.readLine()) != null)
{
     System.out.println(strLine);
     storage.add(strLine.replaceAll("\\s+",""));             
}
```

Comment: @Jeremiah replaceAll() takes the regex. Please try now.

Comment: Now its reading the numbers as 33,34,123,456  instead of 3,3,3,4,1,2,3,4

Comment: [33, 34, 123, 456, 789, 1234, 5678, 9101112]    // is what is printing out

Comment: `[3______3,_3 _4,__ 1_______2_ 3 , ___4 _5 6, 7 8 9, 1 2_ 3_ 4, 5 6 7_ 8, 9 10 11_ 12]` There is no comma `,` in between first and the second 3 and only spaces are there. When you'll remove all the spaces, 33 will be left and not 3,3.

Answer (score 0):

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {

      String total="";
      List list=new ArrayList();
    list.add("3______3");
    list.add("_3 _4");
    list.add("__ 1_______2_ 3");
    list.add("3 ");
    list.add(" ___4 _5 _6");
    list.add(" 7_ 8 _9");

    list.add(" 1_ 2_ 3_ 4");
   list.add(" 5 _6_ 7_ 8");
   list.add(" 9 _10_ 11_ 12");

      String firstname1 = list.toString();
      String regex = "[0-9]+";
      firstname1 = firstname1.replaceAll("_", ",");

      firstname1 = firstname1.replace(",", ",");

      String str = firstname1.toString().replaceAll("\\s+", ",").replace("[", "").replace("]", "");

      String arr[] = str.split(",");

      for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
          if (arr[i].matches(regex)) {

              total += arr[i] + ",";
          }
      }
      total = total.substring(0, total.length() - 1);
      List finalList = Arrays.asList(total);

      System.out.println(finalList);
     //output-->> [3,3,3,4,1,2,3,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
  }
}
```

Comment: below my code this is txt file...  3___________3
3_4

1 ______2 3 
4_5 _6
7 _8 _9

1 _2_ 3_ 4
5 _6 _7 _8
9_ 10_ 11_ 12

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
  {
      String total="";
      List list=new ArrayList();


         try {
           BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( new FileReader("filename.txt"));
            while( (total = br.readLine()) != null)
            {
           list.add(total);             
            }
            br.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.println("Unable to find the file: fileName");
        }

      String firstname1 = list.toString();
      String regex = "[0-9]+";
      firstname1 = firstname1.replaceAll("_", ",");

      firstname1 = firstname1.replace(",", ",");

      String str = firstname1.toString().replaceAll("\\s+", ",").replace("[", "").replace("]", "");

      String arr[] = str.split(",");
      String sum="";
      for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

          if (arr[i].matches(regex)) {

              sum += arr[i] + ",";

          }
      }
      sum = sum.substring(0, sum.length() - 1);
      List finalList = Arrays.asList(sum);

      System.out.println("finallist-->>>"+finalList);
     //output-->> [3,3,3,4,1,2,3,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
  }
}
```

Comment: 3___________3
3_4

1 ______2 3 
4_5 _6
7 _8 _9

1 _2_ 3_ 4
5 _6 _7 _8
9_ 10_ 11_ 12

Comment: output->>[3,3,3,4,1,2,3,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]